# En el MainActivity no se muestran los botones aunque ya lo haya declarado

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

Estoy haciedo un proyecto de la escuela y como se puede observar que tengo declarado el botón guardar con el id btnGuardar, pero cuando lo quiero declarar no me deja como se muestra en la siguiente imagen
[image: se puede observar que tengo declarado el botón guardar con el id btnGuardar, pero cuando lo quiero declarar no me deja como se muestra en la siguiente imagen]

Cuando quiero mandar llamar el evento setOnClickListener ya no puedo, alguien sabe porque?
[image: Cuando quiero mandar llamar el evento setOnClickListener ya no puedo, alguien sabe porque?]

Answer (score 0):

Si  a alguien le ocurrió debe agregar esto en dependencias del archivo build.gradle proyect como se muestra en la imagen

classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-android-extensions:$kotlin_version"

[image: Ejemplo]

Y agregar también lo de a continuación al archivo de build.gradle module como en la imagen de a continuación:

[image: Ejemplo2]